# Can NLTK be used in a Postgres Python Stored Procedure

Tags: postgresql, nlp, nltk

Has anyone done or even no if its possible to use NLTK within a Postgres Python Stored Procedure or trigger

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use pretty much any Python library in a PL/Python stored procedure or trigger.

See the [PL/Python documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html).

### Concepts

The crucial point to understand is that **PL/Python *is* CPython** (in PostgreSQL up to and including 9.3, anyway); it uses exactly the same interpreter that the normal standalone Python does, it just loads it as a library into the PostgreSQL backed. With a few limitations (outlined below), if it works with CPython it works with PL/Python.

If you have multiple Python interpreters installed on your system - versions, distributions, 32-bit vs 64-bit etc - you might need to make sure you're installing extensions and libraries into the right one when running distutils scripts, etc, but that's about it.

Since you can load any library available to the system Python there's no reason to think NLTK would be a problem unless you know it requires things like threading that aren't really recommended in a PostgreSQL backend. (Sure enough, I tried it and it "just worked", see below).

One possible concern is that the startup overhead of something like NLTK might be quite big, you probably want to preload PL/Python it in the postmaster and import the module in your setup code so it's ready when backends start. Understand that the postmaster is the parent process that all the other backends `fork()` from, so if the postmaster preloads something it's available to the backends with greatly reduced overheads. Test performance either way.

### Security

Because you can load arbitrary C libraries via PL/Python and because the Python interpreter has no real security model, `plpythonu` is an "untrusted" language. Scripts have full and unrestricted access to the system as the `postgres` user and can fairly simply bypass access controls in PostgreSQL. For obvious security reasons this means that PL/Python functions and triggers may only be created by the superuser, though it's quite reasonable to `GRANT` normal users the ability to *run* carefully written functions that were installed by the superuser.

The upside is that you can do pretty much anything you can do in normal Python, keeping in mind that the Python interpreter's lifetime is that of the database connection (session). Threading isn't recommended, but most other things are fine.

PL/Python functions must be written with careful input sanitation, must set `search_path` when invoking the SPI to run queries, etc. This is discussed more in the manual.

### Limitations

Long-running or potentially problematic things like DNS lookups, HTTP connections to remote systems, SMTP mail delivery, etc should generally be done from a helper script using `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` rather than an in-backend job in order to preserve PostgreSQL's performance and avoid hampering `VACUUM` with lots of long transactions. You can do these things in the backend, it just isn't a great idea.

You should avoid creating threads within the PostgreSQL backend.

Don't attempt to load any Python library that'll load the `libpq` C library. This could cause all sorts of exciting problems with the backend. When talking to PostgreSQL from PL/Python use the SPI routines not a regular client library.

Don't do very long-running things in the backend, you'll cause vacuum problems.

Don't load anything that might load a different version of an already loaded native C library - say a different libcrypto, libssl, etc.

Don't write directly to files in the PostgreSQL data directory, *ever*.

PL/Python functions run as the `postgres` system user on the OS, so they don't have access to things like the user's home directory or files on the client side of the connection.

### Test result

```
$ yum install python-nltk python-nltk
$ psql -U postgres regress

regress=# CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;

regress=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nltk_word_tokenize(word text) RETURNS text[] AS $$
          import nltk
          return nltk.word_tokenize(word)
          $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

regress=# SELECT nltk_word_tokenize('This is a test, it''s going to work fine');
              nltk_word_tokenize               
-----------------------------------------------
 {This,is,a,test,",",it,'s,going,to,work,fine}
(1 row)
```

So, as I said: Try it. So long as the Python interpreter PostgreSQL is using for plpython has nltk's dependencies installed it will work fine.

### Note

PL/Python is CPython, but I'd love to see a PyPy based alternative that can run untrusted code using PyPy's sandbox features.

Comment: Not sure I understand your response. I've have read the link that you provided and it actually does not specify any explicit limitations that I can see hence the question; have I missed something?

Comment: @user2064232 What limitations do you expect to find? What are you concerned about? *did you try it*? (Oh, just noticed a possible wording problem in my answer. Corrected and answer elaborated considerably).

Comment: "Limitations" It wont work; "Concerns" I asked Streamhacker aka Jacob Perkins about running NLTK in Iron Python and he said it would not work due to numpy and C library dependencies. "Did I try it" uh that was the point of my post i.e if some one had and failed I might save my self some time and if not then I'll try it!  clearly the answer is no one has tried or no one knows the answer!

Comment: @user2064232 C library dependencies and numpy should not be a problem in PL/Python.

Comment: @user2064232 It works fine, see updated answer. I'm a bit disappointed that NLTK doesn't seem to even tokenize `it's` correctly, but maybe you have to set a language for that or something.

Comment: @user2064232 I think your key point of confusion may've been assuming that PL/Python is a separate Python implementation. It is not. It just embeds CPython in the PostgreSQL interpreter.

Comment: Thanks this clarifies things greatly and will give it a ago. Apologies for the late response, been on holiday.

Comment: As a follow-up to this question, I am curious whether it is possible to use numpy functions as aggregate functions directly. It seems like the only way to create an aggregate function is to create a custom accumulator data type and then write a row-wise function that mutates the state of the accumulator. But for something like `np.median`, the goal should be to express some way of just executing that function, as-is, on an entire column with correctly typed values. Needing to mutate state by hand removes all benefit of the already-vectorized numpy implementations.

Comment: @Mr.F Quite unrelated; separate question please. Feel free to at-mention me.

Comment: @ely that's a very interesting take. Did you get to the bottom of it? It seems one would be better off just loading the data up in python to process it there, using standard sql to numpy/pandas conversions (perhaps having to store it back on the database afterwards.